# How to set HttpPost and a header for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, http, http-headers, http-post

When I search for this question I always get the answer for "How to set header WITH JavaScript" but I want to set the HttpPost Header FOR JavaScript.

I try to Formlogon on a Website, but the response tell me that I need JavaScript. So how can I fake JavaScript? Do I need a Cookie? or a Header? Isn't it possible to set a header "JavaScript" with Version x?

I think there must be a way to do this :-)
I dont want to show the user a Website, i only want to login with the Users information and parse the result for some informations the user needs. Thats it.

Thanks

**EDIT:** maybe its a good idea to explain what i want to try:
I try to login to a mobilephone provider website with my auth-data and reading out the current consumption data and the bank balancce for this account. And i dont want to login everytime to see this with my phone! And i also want the EXACT data not only the self calculated data from any app wich can calculate it! :)

Comment: What exactly is the full response?

Comment: i get the response with response.getEntity().getContent() and than i write it to the Log. And i did the same in my browser. In the response he tell me that i need to activate JavaScript if i want to use this service.

Answer (score 0):

I think the availabilty of Javascript is not determined in the HttpPost but usually made with a combination of client/server side code. An example is available [here](http://sveinbjorn.org/check_if_javascript_is_enabled).

Comment: i dont try to logon on my oun website. I cant change anything on the server side. I only try to login on this website with setting username and password (like it is called in the code of the website) and send a POST with that information.